# Branching Processes - Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, markov-chains, markov-process, binomial-distribution, branching-rules

Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be a branching process, with $X_0=1$

Given $Z \text{~} Binomial(2,\frac{1}{3})$. Find the probability that the branching process becomes extinct.

My Workings:

$G(S)= \mathbb{E}(s^Z) = (ps + q)^n = s$

$= (\frac{1}{3}s + \frac{2}{3})^2 = s$

$=\frac{1}{9}s^2 + \frac{4}{3}s + \frac{4}{9} = s$

$=\frac{1}{9}s^2 + \frac{1}{3}s + \frac{4}{9} = 0$

However, $S=1$ is then not a solution, which I thought it always had to be, so I think I have made a mistake / have misunderstood something?

Comment: I have made a  mistake in my answer. Please cancel the approval for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\frac{1}{3}s + \frac{2}{3})^{2}$ should have been $(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{2s}{3})^{2}$ and the equation is $4s^{2}-5s+1=0$ of which $s=1$ is a solution.

Comment: I disagree here, $\mathbb{E}[Z] = \frac{2}{3}$ yields certain extinction. @Kavi's equation yields two solutions in the interval $[0,1]$, this should not be the case as $\mathbb{E}[Z]<1 $. The MGF was correct $G(s) = \left( 1-p + ps\right)^2$, where $p = \frac{1}{3}$. In the question calculation there is a mistake while expanding the square, the term $\frac{4}{3}s$ should have been $\frac{4}{9}s$ and so we get $\frac{1}{9}s^2 - \frac{5}{9}s + \frac{4}{9} = 0$ or $s^2 - 5s+4=0$ that yields the unique solution $s=1$ in the interval $[0, 1]$.@Kavi, do you agree with me?

Comment: @m_gnacik You are right. I will delete my answer as soon as the approval is cancelled. You can post your answer after that.